# Cannot find file or constant when using a gem locally in a Rails app

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3.2, rubygems, bundler

I have a gem that I am making and it is located at the same level as a rails app.

I am trying to use the gem in the rails app, but am not able to make it work - the constant I am trying to use, which is defined in the gem, is not accessible to the rails app for some reason.

What am I doing wrong here? What steps can I take to begin debugging the cause of the problem?

In the rails console, `$:.grep /mygem/` shows me `["/Users/zabba/mygem/lib"]`

Directory structure, with the contents of certain files:

```
~/mygem/
  lib/
    mygem/
      some_class.rb
        module Mygem
          class SomeClass
          end 
        end
    mygem.rb
      require 'mygem/some_class'

~/railsapp/
    Gemfile:
      gem 'mygem', path: '../mygem', require: 'mygem'
    app/
      models/
        a_model.rb:
          # require 'mygem' cannot find file
          class AModel
            def hello_world
              SomeClass.new # Cannot find constant
              Mygem::SomeClass.new # Cannot find constant
            end
          end
```

Comment: Can you tell me where have you kept the Gem in which folder ?

Comment: What's the (relevant part of the) directory structure of `mygem`?  I think you need to have `mygem/lib/mygem.rb`, and `mygem.rb` should have your classes defined there (or it should require files which define those classes).  You can also `puts $LOAD_PATH` at the top of `a_model.rb` to see whether Bundler has put your gem's source on the load path, thereby allowing you to require `mygem`.

Comment: AnkitG/ Amit Kumar Gupta, added the directory structure of the gem folder as well.

Answer (score 0):

Can you create a folder `vendor/gems` and copy your gem in there.  Then in you Gemfile

Gemfile

```
gem 'mygem', :path => "vendor/gems/mygem-0.0.1"
```

Then `bundle install`